# How to dynamically create dataframes with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code currently looks like this:

```
df_1 = portfolio_all[0].rename(columns={'Close': 'Close_1'} )
df_2 = portfolio_all[1].rename(columns={'Close': 'Close_2'} ) 
df_3 = portfolio_all[2].rename(columns={'Close': 'Close_3'} ) 
df_4 = portfolio_all[3].rename(columns={'Close': 'Close_4'} )
df_5 = portfolio_all[4].rename(columns={'Close': 'Close_5'} ) 


df_1['daily_return_1'] = df_1['Close_1'].pct_change(1)  
df_2['daily_return_2'] = df_2['Close_2'].pct_change(1)   
df_3['daily_return_3'] = df_3['Close_3'].pct_change(1)   
df_4['daily_return_4'] = df_4['Close_4'].pct_change(1)   
df_5['daily_return_5'] = df_5['Close_5'].pct_change(1)      



df_1['perc_ret_1'] = (1 + df_1.daily_return_1).cumprod() - 1  
df_2['perc_ret_2'] = (1 + df_2.daily_return_2).cumprod() - 1  
df_3['perc_ret_3'] = (1 + df_3.daily_return_3).cumprod() - 1  
df_4['perc_ret_4'] = (1 + df_4.daily_return_4).cumprod() - 1  
df_5['perc_ret_5'] = (1 + df_5.daily_return_5).cumprod() - 1
```

Is there a way to dynamically create these dataframes in a for loop or something like that without having to write each dataframe as a line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create using a simple python `for-loop` and `enumerate` throught he `list`

```
import pandas as pd

portfolio_all = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]  

for i, df in enumerate(portfolio_all):
    column_name = f'Close_{i+1}'
    df.rename(columns={'Close': column_name}, inplace=True)
    df[f'daily_return_{i+1}'] = df[column_name].pct_change(1)
    df[f'perc_ret_{i+1}'] = (1 + df[f'daily_return_{i+1}']).cumprod() - 1
```

Assuming you have all the dataframes as a list.

This way, you can avoid repeating the same code for each DataFrame, and it should work for any number of DataFrames in your `portfolio_all` list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: use `enumerate(portfolio_all, 1)` to start counting `i` at `1`

Answer (score 1):

Let's:

- Dynamically create new DataFrames without modifying the originals, and
- store them in a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {}

# Loop through each DataFrame in portfolio_all
for i, original_df in enumerate(portfolio_all):
    # Copy the DataFrame to avoid modifying the original
    df = original_df.copy()
    
    close_column_name = f'Close_{i+1}'
    df.rename(columns={'Close': close_column_name}, inplace=True)
    daily_return_column_name = f'daily_return_{i+1}'
    df[daily_return_column_name] = df[close_column_name].pct_change(1)
        perc_ret_column_name = f'perc_ret_{i+1}'
    df[perc_ret_column_name] = (1 + df[daily_return_column_name]).cumprod() - 1
    
    # Store the modified DataFrame in the dictionary
    df_dict[f'df_{i+1}'] = df

# df_dict contains all your modified DataFrames so can access them like this:
# df_1_modified = df_dict['df_1']
# df_2_modified = df_dict['df_2']
# ...
```